# xsession error: cannot log in after changing environment variable

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login, root

I tried setting a new environment variable (I use linux mint 17). After restarting, I couldn't log back in. It says:

> Your Session only lasted less thant 10 Seconds. If you have not logged
>   out yourself, this could mean that there is some installation problem
>   or that you may be out of diskspace. Try logging in with on of the
>   failsafe sessions to see if you can fix this problem.

the ~/.xsession-errors file contains the following:

> /etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup /etc/mdm/Xsession:: 3:
>   export:
>   :/home/myusername/mallet-2.0.7/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:
>   bad variable name

so I basically tried to change the environment variable, trashed something in the process and can't log in. How can I repair this without logging in, while keeping all the data on my computer?

The command I used for changing the environment variable was

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/myusername/mallet-2.0.7/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/myusername/mallet-2.0.7/" >> ~/.bashrc`

So, that's going to interpolate the existing value for $PATH into your .bashrc, and not the string '$PATH'.  Probably not what you intended.

Comment: Also, the error you are getting makes me think you used: `export $PATH=$PATH...`, because it's claiming that you're using ":/home/myusername/mallet-2.0.7/:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin" as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably still be able to log in in text mode. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and enter your user name and password at the `login:` and `password:` prompts, then run `sudo -s` to get a root shell. If you have a root password, you can log in as root directly.

The error looks like a failed attempt to set `PATH`. It's consistent with having an extra space in an assignment, like

```
export PATH= …$PATH…
```

instead of `export PATH=…$PATH…` (or just `PATH=…$PATH…`).

Depending on the exact nature of the problem, it may be reported at the point where the actual error is or later. To edit `/etc/mdm/Xsession`, run

```
nano /etc/mdm/Xsession
```

If that's not where the error is, check in your dot files and other files in `/etc`.

```
grep -s mallet-2.0.7 ~/.* /etc/* /etc/*/Xsession*
```

Once you think you've fixed the error (feel free to ask a new question on this site if you aren't sure how), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the GUI login prompt. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back and forth between the virtual consoles at any time.

Comment: your second sentence just saved my life.  seriously.  i was going to go get a drink.  thanks.......!  i've only worked off linux servers, this is my first at home laptop.  i don't know anything all over again.

Answer (score 1):

So I also asked for help on the Linux Mint forums and some awesome user solved my problem. Apparently, by using the above command I modified the content of /etc/environment. It should only contain the following:

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:"

To change that I had to enter as root in the recovery shell, change the partion to read/write using:

```
mount -o remount,rw  /
```

and than edit /etc/environment using

```
nano /etc/environment
```

alternatively you can edit the /etc/environment as root:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Now it works again.

Answer (score -1):

How did you got the screen for text mode after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

i did the same changes as you have done and facing same issue, i am not able to login in server and tried lot of way.
kindly provide me steps to revert for my changes.
it will be very help full for me.